# Returning a static cast to a pointer doesn't return a pointer C++

Tags: c++, function, oop, pointers, static-cast

In an "Entity" class, there is a function that takes in a component typename as an argument, and **should** return a **pointer** to that component, if found in the component array. Instead it just returns a copy of the component, not a pointer, despite doing this:

```cpp
return static_cast<T*>(ptr)
```

Here is the relevant code:

**ECS.h** (only the necessary code).

```cpp
inline ComponentTypeId getUniqueComponentID() {
    static ComponentTypeId lastID = 0u;
    return lastID++;
}

template <typename T> inline ComponentTypeId getComponentTypeID() noexcept {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "Failed at getComponentTypeID/static_assert() --> ECS/ECS.h");
    static const ComponentTypeId typeID = getUniqueComponentID();
    return typeID;
}

// Base "Component" class
class Component {
    // Code
};

// Base "Entity" class
class Entity {
    private:
        ComponentArray compArr;
        ComponentBitset compBitset;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;

        bool active = true;

    public:
        Entity() {}
        virtual ~Entity() {}

        template<typename T> bool hasComponent() const {
            // Returns the bitset (bool value)
            return compBitset[getComponentTypeID<T>()];
        }

        template<typename T> T& getComponent() const {
            // Returns pointer to component
            return *static_cast<T*>(compArr[getComponentTypeID<T>()]);
        }

        void update() {
            // Goes through all the components (for this entity) calls their update method
            for(auto &c : components) c->update();
        }

        void draw() {
            // Goes through all the components (for this entity) calls their draw method
            for(auto &c : components) c->draw();
        }

        inline bool isActive() {return active;}
        void destroy() {active = false;}
};
```

Comment: *I forgot to include a semicolon on line 4 for the example, but that doesn't change the problem as it is there in the code.

Comment: Your function returns a reference, not a pointer. It does not make a copy however. Please show how you are actually using the function and what the problem there is. Also reduce your code to a [mre]. The shown usage doesn't work because your function doesn't return a pointer, but a reference. `static_cast<T*>(ptr)` is a pointer, adding a `*` will dereference the pointer.

Comment: @AviBerger The function returns by-reference. There is no obvious point where a copy would be made in the shown code.

Comment: @user17732522, true. I hadn't read passed the first few lines of the post to the point where the full function code was.

Comment: even changin `*static_cast<T*>(ptr)` to `static_cast<T*>(ptr)` doesn't resolve the compile error. Here is the error:
`
In file included from ./src/ECS/components.h:11:0,
                 from ./src/game.cpp:7:
./src/ECS/hitbox_component.h: In member function 'virtual void HitboxComponent::init()':
./src/ECS/hitbox_component.h:25:23: error: cannot convert 'TransformComponent' to 'TransformComponent*' in assignment
             transform = parent->getComponent<TransformComponent>();
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
`

Comment: The code doesn't do what the comment says.  The return type is a reference to T, not a pointer to T.  It seems someone changed the code without changing the comment.

Comment: @KeshavV. Did you also change the return type from reference to pointer?

Comment: If you want to return a pointer, you don't want the leading asterisk. You would include that asterisk to return a reference. As long as the object and its lifetime is correct, either approach could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was returning a reference instead of a pointer in the getComponent() function.

```cpp
template<typename T> T& getComponent() const {
    // Returns pointer to component
    return *static_cast<T*>(compArr[getComponentTypeID<T>()]);
}

// Needs to be
template<typename T> T* getComponent() const {
    // Returns pointer to component
    return static_cast<T*>(compArr[getComponentTypeID<T>()]);
}
```

[image: Original Comment]